# SyndicationElementExtension with namespace

Tags: c#, html, .net, rss, rss2

I want to get this result:

```
<someNSalias:full-text>Good news everyone!</someNSalias:full-text>
```

so i'm writing a code:

```
var elm = new SyndicationElementExtension(field.Name, field.HasNamespace ? RssNs : string.Empty,field.Value);
result.ElementExtensions.Add(elm);
```

but i get:

```
<full-text xmlns="someNS">Good news everyone!</full-text>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: should add this NS localy (in feed as Attribute), and remove it when all's done

Ex:

```
        var feed = new SyndicationFeed(Config.Title, Config.Description, new Uri(Config.Link), Config.ListUrl, DateTime.Now)
        {
            ImageUrl = new Uri(Config.ImageUrl),
            Generator = GetType().BaseType.FullName + "Generator"
        };

        feed.AttributeExtensions.Add(new XmlQualifiedName(RssNs, XNamespace.Xmlns.NamespaceName), Url);
```